# How to append an image to a cell value conditionally in a table. Its in a JSP and im using display tags for the table

Tags: java, jsp, displaytag

I have a data table displayed in a JSP using DisplayTags. One of the columns in the table is a 'Priority' column. If the priority is 1, i have to be able to display a red light beside it. Is there any straight forward way of doing this?

```
<display:column headerClass="tableHead" title="Priority" property="priority" sortable="false" />
```

I need to be able to show an image beside all cells with data value '1'.

Update: i still dont see the image even though it dosent give an exception.

```
<display:column headerClass="tableHead" title="Priority" property="priority" sortable="false" ><c:if test="${dispatchresults1.priority eq 1}"><img src="images/flashinglight4.gif"/></c:if> </display:column>
```

This is the top of my table.

```
    <display:table htmlId="dispatchtable1" id="dispatchresults1" name="packedNotDispatchedlist" pagesize="20" style="width:100%;text-align:left;font-size:10px" class="thinBorder" requestURI=""   export="true" >
```

**Update: This is what worked for me finally.**

```
<display:column headerClass="tableHead" title="Priority"  sortable="false" > 
<c:choose>
<c:when test="${dispatchresults1.priority eq 1}"><img src="images/flashinglight4.gif"/>
</c:when>
<c:otherwise >${dispatchresults1.priority}
</c:otherwise>
</c:choose>             
</display:column>
```

Comment: It would help if you edited your question to include your code and explain what you have tried so far.

Comment: Hi Aaron .I included the column code to give you an idea. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<display:column headerClass="tableHead" title="Priority" sortable="false">
    <c:if test="${tableId.priority == 1}"><img src="..."/></c:if>
</display:column>
```

Comment: Thanks JB. But i still dont see the image even though it dosent give an exception.
        <display:column headerClass="tableHead" title="Priority" property="priority" sortable="false" ><c:if test="${dispatchresults1.priority eq 1}"><img src="images/flashinglight4.gif"/></c:if> </display:column>

This is the top of my table.


        <display:table htmlId="dispatchtable1" id="dispatchresults1" name="packedNotDispatchedlist" pagesize="20" style="width:100%;text-align:left;font-size:10px" class="thinBorder" requestURI=""   export="true" >

Comment: Remove the property attribute from your column.

Comment: I tried this and it worked. Thanks JB.

        <display:column headerClass="tableHead" title="Priority"  sortable="false" > 
              <c:choose>
          <c:when test="${dispatchresults1.priority eq 1}"><img src="images/flashinglight4.gif"/>
                </c:when>
          <c:otherwise >${dispatchresults1.priority}
             </c:otherwise>
    </c:choose>             
             </display:column>

Comment: But now i have a new problem. I also provide an option to export to excel.. also using displaytag. I see the <img src="images/flashinglight4.gif"/> tag in the excel output.

Comment: Use two columns: one with the image, with the media attribute set to html, and one with the text you want in Excel, with the media attribute set to excel. This is described in the tag reference: http://www.displaytag.org/1.2/displaytag/tagreference.html#display-el:column